# lxml - insert nested Element

Tags: python, xpath, nested, lxml, element

I understand that adding a subelement can be done using `element.insert(old_element, new_element)`, and that a nested subelement can be inserted by sequentially replacing the parents all the way up to the root - hovewever is there a function or method of doing this without the said parent replacements? i.e.

```
>>> et.tostring(el) 
>>>>
"""
<b>
    <c/>
    <c/>
    <d>
        <e/>
            <p>
                <a>
                    <q/>
                    <q/>
                <a/>
            </p>
        <e/>
    <d>
    <c/>
    <c/>
<b>
"""
>>>> new = insert_nested_child_element(el, "./d/e/p/a", 3, et.Element('new'))
>>>> et.tostring(new)
"""
<b>
    <c/>
    <c/>
    <d>
        <e/>
            <p>
                <a>
                    <q/>
                    <q/>
                    <new/>
                <a/>
            </p>
        <e/>
    <d>
    <c/>
    <c/>
<b>
"""
```

Comment: Could you please add sample XMLs before and after for demonstration purposes? Thanks.

Comment: Yep - that's been done.

Answer (score 0):

Subelements carry root tree data, so to get updated root use `updated_subelement.getroottree().getroot()`:

```
>>> nested_child_parent_results = el.xpath("./d/e/p/a")
>>> nested_child_parent = nested_child_parent_results[0]
>>> nested_child_parent.getroottree().getroot()
```